# How to close process handle in C#

Tags: c#, process, handle

I have a process that has two different handles. I want to close one or the other based off of their handle ID. Is there a way to do this in c#.

Comment: Did you invoke [DuplicateHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms724251.aspx) to create the second one?

Comment: I did not. I am trying to close a handle that opened by adobe. I opened two pdf's; when I look at the adobe process depending on which file I am actively looking at it shows the handle and ID. I want to close one of the windows based on the handle. If that is not possible please let me know if there is another way.

Comment: So you are not trying to close a duplicate handle of the process, but close the window by it's `hWnd`, right?

Comment: If hWnd is the handle, yes.

Comment: Aren't there two processes? Or you are sure there's only one process but are two windows?

Comment: I have 2 different pdf files open. In taskmgr -> processes there are (2) adobe processes but only once process is handling my two windows. If I maximize one then look at the process in Visual studio debugger I see a handle# 560 ID 428. If I maximize the other and reanalyze in the debugger the handle changes to 952 but the ID of 428 stays the same.

Comment: The title is misleading. A process handle is not the same thing as a window handle. Window handles are not closed. Windows are closed.

Comment: How would you close the window then? By the title?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public partial class TestClass {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

    public delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam);

    public static void TestMethod() {
        var targetName="AcroRd32.exe";

        var processArray=(
            from process in Process.GetProcesses()
            let moduleName=(new Func<Process, String>(x => {
                try {
                    return x.MainModule.ModuleName;
                }
                catch(Win32Exception e) {
                    return default(String);
                }
            }))(process)
            where null!=moduleName
            where 0==String.Compare(targetName, moduleName, true)
            select process).ToArray();

        EnumWindows(
            (hwnd, lParam) => {
                foreach(var process in processArray)
                    if(process.MainWindowHandle==hwnd)
                        return !process.CloseMainWindow();

                return true;
            },
            IntPtr.Zero
            );
    }
}
```